# AdminLTE Dashboard Active class remove

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using AdminLTE dashboard. In sidebar treeview menu active class remove after click on menu.

[AdminLTE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FVW8C.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please review the following post and update the question appropriately:

https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

**Add this javaScript in your footer**

> *this works for adminlte sidebar menu and also for sidebar menu treeview

```
    /** add active class and stay opened when selected */
var url = window.location;

// for sidebar menu entirely but not cover treeview
$('ul.sidebar-menu a').filter(function() {
    return this.href == url;
}).parent().siblings().removeClass('active').end().addClass('active');

// for treeview
$('ul.treeview-menu a').filter(function() {
    return this.href == url;
}).parentsUntil(".sidebar-menu > .treeview-menu").siblings().removeClass('active').end().addClass('active');
```